# Webmaster Tools page inspection failed

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, 404, http, bing-webmaster-tools

In Bing Webmaster Tools I have inspected the homepage URL of my website. I get the following error:

```
Crawl
Last crawl attempted
27 Apr 2023 at 03:00
Crawl allowed?
Yes
Page Fetch
Failed
The Inspected URL returned HTTP 4xx error when we tried to fetch the content. Please make sure that this is intentional. If you have moved the page to a new location, please use proper redirects.
```

I suspect this has something to do with my .htaccess code redirecting visitors to the `https` and adding `www`. to the URL? My code is below:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

UPDATE
My web host has looked into the problem. The Bing bot was being denied access by security. The host has whitelisted the bot. So hopefully in a few days this will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The error states that it is not getting a 301 redirect, but instead a 4xx (probably 404). Check your page headers to understand what is your page actually sending (you can use your browsers' development tools, or, use an external tool).

I would suggest for you to modify your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It basically has broken down your requirements into 2 separate commands. The first redirects http to https. The second, redirects www to non-www.

Comment: Thanks. Don't understand htaccess code, so that is very useful.